# Grouping Json/XML collection using lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, odata, lodash

I have following query in order to select the item, unit and quantity of sales order lines:

```
var urlBestSoldItemDaily = sharedProperties.fooApi + 
    "/salesinvoice/SalesInvoices?$expand=SalesInvoiceLines&" +
    "$select=SalesInvoiceLines/ItemCode,SalesInvoiceLines/UnitCode,SalesInvoiceLines/Quantity&"
```

The result is something like this:

```
<entry>
<id>https://foo/api/salesinvoice/SalesInvoices(guid'607897fa-44aa-4626-a151-1b084bc9d149')</id>
<m:inline>
    <feed>
      <title type="text">SalesInvoiceLines</title>
      <id>https://foo/api/salesinvoice/SalesInvoices(guid'607897fa-44aa-4626-a151-1b084bc9d149')/SalesInvoiceLines</id>
      <entry>
        <id>https://foo/api/salesinvoice/SalesInvoiceLines(guid'2cdf60c3-3430-4d6c-a58a-b7e96f9d6be6')</id>
        <content type="application/xml">
          <m:properties>
            <d:ItemCode>IND43007</d:ItemCode>
            <d:Quantity m:type="Edm.Double">2</d:Quantity>
            <d:UnitCode>box</d:UnitCode>
          </m:properties>
        </content>
      </entry>
    </feed>
  </m:inline>
```

I want to perform grouping on item-unit and then select the top 10 of the result list sorted by quantity, using lodash. I tried using following for grouping but it doesn't work:

```
var list = _.groupBy(data.d.results, 'SalesInvoiceLines.ItemCode, SalesInvoiceLines.UnitCode');
```

How can I perform the grouping so I would have a collection of grouped item and unit with total quantity?

Comment: Your JSON looks suspiciously like XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how you could do it:

```
  var sales = [
    {itemCode: "0001", quantity: 2, unitItem: "box"  },
    {itemCode: "0002", quantity: 2, unitItem: "box"  },
    {itemCode: "0003", quantity: 3, unitItem: "boxx" },
    {itemCode: "0004", quantity: 3, unitItem: "boxxx"},
    {itemCode: "0005", quantity: 1, unitItem: "boxxx"}
  ];

  /*
   * I want to perform grouping on item-unit and then select the top 10
   * of the result list sorted by quantity, using lodash.
  */

  var calcQuantities = function(sales) {

    var sum = function(total, curr) {
      return total + curr.quantity;
    };

    return _.reduce(sales, sum, 0);
  };

  var toQuantitySale = function(sales) {
    return {
      quantity: calcQuantities(sales),
      sales   : sales
    };
  };

  var sortDesc = function(sale) {
    return -sale.quantity;
  };

  // Steps
  var groupedSales  = _.groupBy(sales, 'unitItem')

  var quantitySales = _.map(groupedSales, toQuantitySale)

  var sortedSales   = _.sortBy(quantitySales, sortDesc)

  var top10Sales    = _.take(sortedSales, 10)

  console.log(top10Sales);

  // shorter
  top10Sales =
    _.chain(sales)
     .groupBy('unitItem')
     .map(toQuantitySale)
     .sortBy(sortDesc)
     .take(10)
     .value()
```

Comment: still, with this method also, I can't get the grouped array. what am I missing? I want an array as result with grouped item code and unit in which the quantity is total of the grouped.

Comment: Not sure what you think you want. I think you want something like `{ 'SalesInvoiceLines.ItemCode, SalesInvoiceLines.UnitCode': 2 }`. And I think you can get it by calculating `list` as above, then calculating `_.map(list, sum)`, if you define a function `sum` which takes one of the arrays inside `list` and returns a number by summing the `d:Quantity` numbers inside it.

Comment: @SiavoshTehrani, I edited my answer check if it works for you now and it is exactly how David Knipe describes.

Comment: Thanks @FaustoBencosme!